# Как лучше всего заменить BB-code?

Tags: php, mysql

Как лучше всего заменить BB-code? Заменить при выводе текста или при записи в БД?
Я создал форму, где использую BB-code, но вот не знаю, как лучше всего заменить их. Подскажите, кто знает. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего при выводе текста, если записывать в БД, то к примеру, не сможешь редактировать эти BB коды.

К примеру, перед выводом пропускать текст через эту функцию:

```
function parse_bb_code($text)   {
    $text = preg_replace('/\[(\/?)(b|i|u|s)\s*\]/', "<$1$2>", $text);

    $text = preg_replace('/\[code\]/', '<pre><code>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\[\/code\]/', '</code></pre>', $text);

    $text = preg_replace('/\[(\/?)quote\]/', "<$1blockquote>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\[(\/?)quote(\s*=\s*([\'"]?)([^\'"]+)\3\s*)?\]/', "<$1blockquote>Цитата $4:<br>", $text);

    $text = preg_replace('/\[url\](?:http:\/\/)?([a-z0-9-.]+\.\w{2,4})\[\/url\]/', "<a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\[url\s?=\s?([\'"]?)(?:http:\/\/)?([a-z0-9-.]+\.\w{2,4})\1\](.*?)\[\/url\]/', "<a href=\"http://$2\">$3</a>", $text);

    $text = preg_replace('/\[img\s*\]([^\]\[]+)\[\/img\]/', "<img src='$1'/>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\[img\s*=\s*([\'"]?)([^\'"\]]+)\1\]/', "<img src='$2'/>", $text);

    return $text;
}
```

Список поддерживаемых тегов и синтаксиса:

- [b][/b]
- [i][/i]
- [u][/u]
- [s][/s]
- [code][/code]
- [quote][/quote]
- [quote="Vasya"][/quote]
- [url]адрес[/url]
- [url="adress"]анкор[/url]
- [img]адрес[/img]
- [img="adress"]

Comment: function BB($var) {
 $search = array(
   '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is',
   '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/is',
   '/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/is',
   '/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/is',
   '/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is',
   '/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is',
   '/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is',
   '/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is'
   );

 $replace = array(
   '<b>$1</b>',
   '<i>$1</i>',
   '<u>$1</u>',
   '<pre class="brush: js;">$1</pre>',
   '<img src="$1" />',
   '<blockquote class="quote">$1</blockquote>',
   '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
   '<a href="$1">$2</a>'
   );
 $var = preg_replace ($search, $replace, $var);
 return $var;
}

Comment: Я это использовал. ВИдно, Что фиговая функция)) Спасибо

Comment: ReaGed LLC, не знаете, где взять нормальную форму для комментариев?

Comment: @bellator001: https://github.com/wbb/WysiBB